# Comparing values from a column in Jtable to items in comboboxes

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I need an if statement wrapped around a button that checks the jtable for the EXACT pair of 2 values...if it is false, it adds the entry in textbox and 2 cbboxes to the table, else it prints out an error. So far I've come up with this:

```
lblWarn2.setText("");
DefaultTableModel model =  (DefaultTableModel) tblSold.getModel();
//get value at

if(!cbCruises.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(tblSold.getValueAt(1, 0).toString())&!cbCabin.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(tblSold.getValueAt(1,2).toString()))

{

    model.addRow(new Object[]{cbCruises.getSelectedItem().toString(), txtBuyer.getText(),cbCabin.ToString()});

} 
else 
{
lblWarn2.setText("Cabin full");
}
```

(this table has 3 columns; Cruises, Buyer, Cabin btw)
 Is there a method I can use instead of getValueAt or how can i refactor it so that it will go through the specified 2 columns and search for these values, then compare them to the selected items in comboboxes?

EDIT1; Changed the if statement and it does what it was supposed to be doing at the exact value of row. But is there a method that lets me run through all the rows in a selected column?

Comment: StIngs aren't compared with != or ==, so that's a problem, I don't know what ERROR is the number of rows in the table, so that's no help either

Comment: changed it to model.addRow(new Object[]{cbCruises.getSelectedItem().toString(), txtBuyer.getText(),Cabin.getSelectedItem().toString()});     . Error is what netbeans defaults to if you leave it empty. Leaving it empty doesn't work as I wanted it to though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end my solution looked like this:

```
lblWarn2.setText("");
        DefaultTableModel model =  (DefaultTableModel) tblSold.getModel();
        //get value at

        boolean kabTaken = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < tblSold.getModel().getRowCount(); i++) {

            if(cbCruises.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(tblSold.getValueAt(i, 0).toString())&cbCabin.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(tblSold.getValueAt(i,2).toString()))
            {
                kabTaken = true;
            } 
        }

        if (kabTaken) 
        {
            lblWarn2.setText("Cabin taken");             
        }
        else
        {
        model.addRow(new Object[]{cbCruises.getSelectedItem().toString(), txtBuyer.getText(),cbCabin.getSelectedItem().toString()});    

        }
```

Basically you just encapsulate the if statement into a for loop.